# coinbase transaction pending for nearly 6 months

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I have sent around 0.2 bitcoin from cex.io to coinbase on june 30th and it is still pending up until now. I have tried some transaction accelerator services but when i type in my transaction id it says the transaction has already been comfirmed so i don't know what the cause of the problem is now.. can someone help me? the transation id is 3be4238159edad9e54370a32ef1bad556e98c26d8ab5fd181de3a4b972e8351f. Thank you.

Comment: transaction was confirmed on Jun,30,2017 / if you have any problems - you should contact with your recipient.